# My teleport script causes my player to teleport back to the hub randomly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have an OnTriggerEnter collider, when the player enters the collider it teleports them back to the "hub" which is another OnTriggerEnter collider.

The problem is that the player will be walking along and will randomly teleport back to the hub.

This is the script which is on the OnTriggerEnter collider.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform teleportTarget;
    public Rigidbody player;



    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        player.transform.position = teleportTarget.position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just made it so the collider entering the trigger must be tagged "Player" and that fixed it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform teleportTarget;
    public Rigidbody player;


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            player.transform.position = teleportTarget.position;
        }
    }
}
```